# how to retrieve selected row of datagrid into textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using **windows application C#** and I want to Show DataGrid's Selected row data in to my text boxes. i want that as a user click to DataGrid the selected row should show in textboxes
so where i need to put my code?? which event of dataGrid to use
and what i need to write code??
i am trying this but this is not working what is the right way to do this thing?

```
private void gvProdctTypName_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

tbProductTypeName.Text = gvProdctTypName.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void gvProdctTypName_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbProductTypeName.Text = gvProdctTypName.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

I guess you are using `SelectionMode = FullRowSelect` so this should work. Otherwise you will have to access `SelectedCells` instead.